# Gradle dependency management plugin

Tags: gradle

I am trying to run the following minimal gradle build file including the dependency management plugin:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
}

plugins {
    id "java"
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.4.RELEASE"
}
```

But then running gradle fails:

```
* What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'io.spring.dependency-management', version: '1.0.4.RELEASE'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'io.spring.dependency-management:io.spring.dependency-management.gradle.plugin:1.0.4.RELEASE')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 5.0.
See https://docs.gradle.org/4.5.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Is there a missing dependency in the gradle file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin cannot be found because you defined repositories inside your build script and tried to use plugin outside it. Remove buildscript or add repositories for your build file also.
(Dependencies and repositories defined inside build script are accessible in that buildscript scope)

Example:

```
plugins {
    id "java"
    id "io.spring.dependency-management" version "1.0.4.RELEASE"
}

repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
```

Comment: A full answer should include the resulting script... I will happily accept it after checking that it successfully runs.

Comment: @Christophe Do you have any problem running it. You just have to remove `buildscript {` and it's closing `}`.

Comment: actually it does not work: > startup failed:
  build file 'C:\Users\...\build-test.gradle': 8: only buildscript {} and other plugins {} script blocks are allowed before plugins {} blocks, no other statements are allowed

Comment: @Christophe you should put repositories after plugins. I should edit the post.